# Suggestions on setting cron from 11pm to 12am

Tags: shell, cron

Need help in setting cron from 11pm to 12am

```
===
* 22-23,23,0-1 * * *
===
```

but this seems to be not working; can we really set the cron in that time range as 24:00 is 00:00; its also fine to set it from 11pm to 11:59pm.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with [* 23 * * *](https://crontab.guru/#*_23_*_*_*), that is "run every minute while the hour is 23"?

Comment: @ChristianPekeler   Yes, will it stop stop after 60 mins; I was curious on that part.

Comment: Yes, it'll stop.

Answer (score 0):

try "*/10 23,0 * * *" this should trigger at every 10th minute past hour 23 and 0.